How to eliminate nil error that sometimes occurs when opening swift camera?
The code below is the source code to open the front camera
But sometimes
let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera!)

An unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value error sometimes occurs in this area.
(Please note I haven't seen that error, I just checked the logs in crashlytics)
To prevent this error, you can change it as follows. You can prevent the error, but you may not be able to open the camera.
I think the reason you can't open the camera is because another app is holding the camera object.
Is there any way to solve this problem?
if let frontCamera = frontCamera {
    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera)
    stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    
    if captureSession.canAddInput(input) && captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
        captureSession.addInput(input)
        captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
        setupLivePreview()
    }
} else {
    print("Unable to find front camera")
}

//full code
func startCamera() {
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = .high
    
    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified)
    
    for device in deviceDiscoverySession.devices {
        switch device.position {
        case .front:
            frontCamera = device
        case .back:
            backCamera = device
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    do {
        if frontCamera == nil {
            frontCamera = getCamera(with: .front)
        }

        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera)
        stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        
        if captureSession.canAddInput(input) && captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            captureSession.addInput(input)
            captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            setupLivePreview()
        }

    } catch let error {
        print("Error Unable to initialize back camera: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}


There are a lot of things that can go wrong - no permissions to access the camera, no camera like that available on the device, etc.

@iSpain17 -  Thank you for answer. We confirmed that the app does not close even if you do not have camera permission. And it appears that errors are occurring even on models with cameras. The overall error rate is about 0.1%.

The code above has been edited and is not the original code that causes the crash, right?

@iSpain17 - This is the original code.
